# How does ajax work with python?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm been googling around, but I don't quite understand how ajax works. **Could please somebody explain how this works?**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for( 'app.slideshow.<tag>' ) }}",
        type: "",
        data: {'param':},
        dataType: "",
        success : function(response)
        {
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is see if document.getElementsByClassName(current) has changed. If it has, it will ask app.py for comments and tags on current, and update the page without refreshing. I have no idea what to write to receive this on the app.py either.

I'll include my app.py, but it is not good.

```
from flask import Flask,session,url_for,request,redirect,render_template
import api,db   
app = Flask(__name__)
#app.secret_key = "secret"

@app.route('/slideshow/<tag>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def slide():
if request.method=="GET":
    pic = request.get('current').href
    taglist = db.getTaglist()
    tags = db.getTags(pic)
    piclist = db.getPics(<tag>)
    commentlist = db.getComments(pic)
    return render_template("slide.html", taglist = taglist, tags =tags, piclist =piclist, commentlist = commentlist, url = url)
else:   
    button = request.form['button']
    pic = request.get('current').href

    if button=="submit":
        aComment = request.form['comment']
        db.addComment(pic,aComment)
    elif button == "submitnewtag":
        if request.form['Addnewtag']
            aTag = request.form['Addnewtag']
            db.addTag(pic,aTag)
        else:
            aTag =  request.form['select1']
            db.addTag(pic,aTag)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run(port=5300)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question. What exactly are you asking, and what does it have to do with Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, ajax handler on your server should return XML or JSON (I think JSON is better) with the data it needs.

So, after getting info from the handler, dump(cast) it into a JSON object  and return to client.

On client, JavaScript receives this JSON, and after that should dynamically create html elements and insert them in your page body.

Start by exploring [this simple tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/) by Flask's creator.